# Open popup when click on picture and also redirect page on hyper link

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Give me the code of popup.
I need a javascript when user click on picture it will open popup and also redirect the page on picture hyper link.
I tried this one but it only open popup:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/" onclick="javascript:void window.open('http://www.google.com/','1387538381256','width=1000,height=700,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');return false;">

  <img style="height: 200px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0pt; margin-top: 0pt;" alt="IPL 2012" src="http://i.imgur.com/NLUDioo.png" />
</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aqLGB/1/)!

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code it will redirect and also open a pop up

```
<a href="http://amazon.in" onclick="javascript: window.open('http://www.google.com/','1387538381256','width=1000,height=700,toolbar=0,menubar=0,location=0,status=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,left=0,top=0');">

<img style="height: 200px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0pt; margin-top: 0pt;" alt="IPL 2012" src="http://i.imgur.com/NLUDioo.png" />
</a>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YShs2/153/)